# commons.apache.org is affected by log4j?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, log4j, slf4j

I have a maven project with spring-boot.

[image: Spring-boot]

Add this line:
`<properties> <log4j2.version>2.17.1</log4j2.version> </properties>`

Run the command `mvnw dependency:list | grep log4j` and I get this output:
[image]

Also, I did a search on all modules for the string: `logg` and got this result.
[image: searching string logg]

Also, my project has these dependencies:

[image: slf4j dependecies]

So, is my project affected by the LOG4J vulnerability?

How do I mitigate it?

Comment: Do you still have the affected log4j2 classes / JARs in your dependencies?  If not, then you are not affected by log4shell.

Comment: Spring boot uses logback by default so you are not affected. I see no dependencies on log4j2-core in any of that output.

Comment: You can check vulnerabilities on [mvnrepository.com](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/log4j-over-slf4j) (they added the feature after the Log4j vulnerability). `log4j-over-slf4j` is not vulnerable because: 1. it is an SLF4J artifact (only `log4j-core` from Apache Foundation was vulnerable), 2. it is a **replacement** for Log4j **1.x**.

Comment: The first issue is that you are using ancient old version of Spring Boot 1.X which is EoL for a longer time https://spring.io/blog/2018/07/30/spring-boot-1-x-eol-aug-1st-2019

Comment: @khmarbaise, then, Sprint boot 1.X is affected by log4j? and How do I mitigate it?

Comment: First the usage of old software in itself is a problem..log4j is affected in old versions as well because log4j 1.X is 12 years old... You should upgrade your whole application... sorry to say that but thats the really issue here...